# Is there a less colloquial word (noun or adjective) to describe an "attention whore"?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, pejorative-language

It could be a noun or an adjective, and either could describe a person or an action. For example:

*"Did you hear Eric's wedding toast? He wouldn't shut up!"*

*"I know, he was being a complete _______"*

Comment: In recent years, I've heard the term _kardashian_ used.

Comment: @SvenYargs Though that is probably an awesome fit, it is probably even more colloquial.

Comment: +1, I hate the use of the word "whore" as a pejorative.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider **attention seeker**. (or attention-seeker)

> **[attention-seeking](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/attention-seeking)** *(adj)* Attempting to attract the attention of other people, typically by disruptive or excessively extrovert behaviour

---

You can also use **[ostentatious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostentatious)**

> : marked by or fond of conspicuous or vainglorious and sometimes pretentious display
>
> : displaying wealth, knowledge, etc., in a way that is meant to attract attention, admiration, or envy

Answer (score 12):

*"Did you hear Eric's wedding toast? He wouldn't shut up!"*

> *"I know, he was being a complete **showboat/showoff***."

Alternately, you can say:

> *"I know, he was being a complete **grandstander***."

Answer (score 3):

Center of attention; as in Eric always has to be the center of attention.

Answer (score 2):

I usually like to say that..

> the person likes the sound of their own voice

. It's not a one word noun or adjective but fits Eric perfectly.

Garrulous also comes close: Defintion at [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/garrulous)

> Excessively talkative, especially on trivial matters. 
>   Given to prosy, rambling, or tedious loquacity :  pointlessly or annoyingly talkative

Answer (score 1):

Eric was being a **self-centered**, **narcissistic** jerk.

Answer (score 1):

Grandstander or failing that, any of the synonyms posted [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/grandstander)

Answer (score 0):

*Exhibitionist*, as in Eric was being a complete exhibitionist.

Comment: In American English this isn't a good fit because exhibitionist is normally used to refer to someone who exposes parts of his/her body that are normally concealed outside of clothing optional areas.

Answer (score 0):

I know, he was being a complete Stage (or spotlight) hog.

Comment: That's not really "less colloquial"....

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit old, but I felt like "Egomaniac" would be a pretty fitting technical word for the sentence and might be useful to someone somewhere.